# How do you replace a single character with a backslash using regex.replace in c#

Tags: c#, regex

If I do this:

```
Regex.Replace("unlocktheinbox.com", "[t]", "\\$&");
```

My result is:

```
"unlock\\theinbox.com"
```

I'm expecting it to be

```
"unlock\theinbox.com"
```

I'm trying to replace "t" with "\t" using regex.replace. I made this example very basic to explain what I'm trying to accomplish.

Comment: Try this `Regex.Replace("unlocktheinbox.com", "[t]", @"\");`

Comment: Nope, the example you provided works as expected. If you're basing your observations on the watch/locals window in Visual Studio, it just shows `"unlock\\theinbox.com"`, \\ means it's one backslash, but in string it has to be escaped. If you `Console.WriteLine` out the resulting string, it shows up correctly.

Comment: Your output is correct, but the debugger shows the result as a valid C# string. Try to write it to the console for instance and you'll see.

Comment: I was testing in the Immediate window - but now I can see in the console window it is correct.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try following

```
var result = Regex.Replace("unlocktheinbox.com", "[t]", @"\");
```

*Note that, if you observe `result` while debugging via hovering mouse on `result`. it will look like `unlock\\theinbox.com` because `\` is escaped. But actually, if you print `result` or use anywhere it will be `unlock\theinbox.com`*